# Having Invalid column name when the name exist SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an error on the column "PREMIUM" when the premium exist on the select statement. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
SELECT QUIKPLAN.FORMS, COALESCE(NEWQUIKVALF1.MVALDATE, '2022-09-30') AS ReportDate, ISNULL((SUM(NEWQUIKVALF1.MANNLZD)/12),0) AS PREMIUM
FROM QUIKPLAN
LEFT JOIN dbo.NEWQUIKVALF1 ON QUIKPLAN.NEWPLAN=NEWQUIKVALF1.NPLAN
GROUP BY QUIKPLAN.FORMS, NEWQUIKVALF1.MVALDATE
HAVING ((QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-4054' and ((PREMIUM)>1))
```

This code works in Snowflake, but it is not working in SQL Server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what error message exactly

Comment: You can't use calculated columns in the having clause in SQL Server, you need to include that in a sub-query of some sort.

Comment: @nbk Invalid Column name "PREMIUM"

Comment: @Desmond yes we know but that belongs always in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, you cannot access a calculated field within the same query scope. However, you can use the same calculation twice with no penalty.

```
SELECT 
    QUIKPLAN.FORMS, 
    COALESCE(NEWQUIKVALF1.MVALDATE, '2022-09-30') AS ReportDate, 
    ISNULL((SUM(NEWQUIKVALF1.MANNLZD)/12),0) AS PREMIUM
FROM 
    QUIKPLAN
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NEWQUIKVALF1 ON QUIKPLAN.NEWPLAN=NEWQUIKVALF1.NPLAN
GROUP BY QUIKPLAN.FORMS, NEWQUIKVALF1.MVALDATE
HAVING ((QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-4054' and ((ISNULL((SUM(NEWQUIKVALF1.MANNLZD)/12),0))>1))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this :

```
SELECT 
    QUIKPLAN.FORMS
    , COALESCE(NEWQUIKVALF1.MVALDATE, '2022-09-30') AS ReportDate
    , ISNULL((SUM(NEWQUIKVALF1.MANNLZD)/12),0) AS PREMIUM
FROM QUIKPLAN
LEFT JOIN dbo.NEWQUIKVALF1 
   ON QUIKPLAN.NEWPLAN=NEWQUIKVALF1.NPLAN
WHERE (QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-4054'
GROUP BY QUIKPLAN.FORMS, NEWQUIKVALF1.MVALDATE
HAVING ISNULL((SUM(NEWQUIKVALF1.MANNLZD)/12),0) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE for that

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT QUIKPLAN.FORMS, COALESCE(NEWQUIKVALF1.MVALDATE, '2022-09-30') AS ReportDate, ISNULL((SUM(NEWQUIKVALF1.MANNLZD)/12),0) AS PREMIUM
FROM QUIKPLAN
LEFT JOIN dbo.NEWQUIKVALF1 ON QUIKPLAN.NEWPLAN=NEWQUIKVALF1.NPLAN
GROUP BY QUIKPLAN.FORMS, NEWQUIKVALF1.MVALDATE
HAVING QUIKPLAN.FORMS ='L-4054' )

SELECT FORMS, ReportDate,PREMIUM
FROM CTE
WHERE PREMIUM>1
```